# Ftp socket timeout on google cloud function

Tags: node.js, sockets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, ftp

I'm trying a nodejs function to connect to an ftp site and list the files. When I run this function locally everything works perfectly, but when I deploy this as a Google Cloud Function the cloud function keeps timing out with the following exception:

```
Error: Timeout (control socket) at Socket.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/basic-ftp/dist/FtpContext.js:316:58) at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28) at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28) at Socket.emit (domain.js:532:15) at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:484:8) at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17) at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
```

I'm guessing here that communication over the ftp ports aren't allowed by default for google cloud functions but I'm not sure. Could this be the case and if it is how do I allow it? I tried setting firewall rules under VPC Firewall rules but that didn't work even when I set the cloud function to route all traffic through the VPC connector.

What am I missing here?

This is the cloud function I'm trying out:

```
const ftp = require("basic-ftp");

const workingDirectory = "outgoing/";

exports.getAllFtp = functions
  .region("europe-west3")
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const client = new ftp.Client();

    try {
      await client.access({
        host: "ftp.myftpsite.xxx",
        user: "blah blah",
        password: "blah blah blah",
      });
      console.log(await client.list(workingDirectory));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    client.close();

    res.status(200).send("OK");
  });
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the case or not, but it's possible that your library try to create a socket in the in-memory file system and therefore fail to create it (if it's created out of the /tmp directory). I don't know the control that you can have on that, and if it's the real error. I haven't other idea!

Comment: Egress connections are not blocked. You are getting a timeout which means the FTP server is not responding. Double-check which ports the FTP server supports and the protocols.

Comment: can you check IP address whitelisting on the FTP server?

Comment: @al-dann there isn't any IP whitelisting. I can run this code from different locations with different IP's and it works. Just doesn't work when deployed as a cloud function.

Comment: @John Hanley - If the FTP server was the issue then surely this would have failed when running the code outside of the cloud function as well, but it doesn't?

Comment: What are the FTP server ports and protocols? Is your code running in FTP Active or Passive Mode? The FTP directory listing command opens another connection on a different port sometimes in the reverse direction (which will fail on Cloud Functions). Your question does not have enough details to answer. We can only offer hints and tips.

Comment: For example, your home router usually understands the FTP protocol and when the FTP server tries to connect back to your client, the router will NAT the port for you. In Cloud Functions that will not work at all. Only connections from Cloud Function to the FTP server will work.

Comment: Tip: Test an FTP command that does not open a data channel connection. If that works, then you know that the data channel connect back is the problem which means the FTP mode is incorrect.

Comment: The library I used to test is called [basic-ftp](https://github.com/patrickjuchli/basic-ftp). It uses Passive mode. Thanks I'll try a command only test.

Comment: Hi @Bracher, were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @ZeenathSN No. I couldn't get it to work on GCP cloud functions. I now moved it over to AWS lambda functions where it works fine.

Comment: @Bracher have you tried John Hanley Tip? I.e "Test an FTP command that does not open a data channel connection"